# NG-File-Upload Issue

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) on my page. I've tried several different ways to invoke the file upload prompt, including an
`<input type="file" ngf-select="myFunction()" />`

and this

`<a ngf-select="myFunction()"></a>`
I've tried wrapping both of those options in forms, and tried outside of forms. The issue I'm having is that it's really hard to get the file upload prompt to pop up when you click on the link. It only shows up every now and then. The other issue is that the `myFunction()` function is called multiple times even when I can't get the file upload prompt to popup and select a file.

When I am finally able to select a file, the function is called over and over and I get caught in an infinite loop. It seems like I have everything set up the same as [the demo page](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) but it doesn't work. Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you inject the dependance to this module ?

Comment: Yes. It works sometimes. You'll notice I put up above that the function is called multiple times on each click, but that each click doesn't always bring up the file select prompt.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle showing the issue? It might be another conflicting module that manipulates dom.

Comment: One of the problems is that even in Plunker I can't get it running properly. Here, take a look: http://embed.plnkr.co/TX3KpcU1oo4GKY7AB21B/preview.

Comment: is your problem sorted mate?

Comment: try ngf-select="myFunction($file)"